# Property and tenant relationship in a property management web application

Tags: lists

Am working on a Project. An admin user can create tenants and assign properties,buildings or units to the tenant created.  These are the possible scenarios. There can be many buildings in a property and there can be many units in a building. A tenant can occupy a whole property, or a whole building in a property, or decides to occupy a unit in a building inside a property.

[image]

Please what is the best way to go about the input part for the  Tenant Property Information. And i dont want to scroll through the list of properties before finding the one to assign

Comment: How many properties are there?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a common and clear layout.
If an editable grid of tenants is not feasible or if editing tenant info is a very common use case (usually it wouldn't be), you can drop the "Edit" column and instead have a form with tenant info at the bottom of the screen, displaying the data of the tenant selected in the grid.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNvyLW.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Tree structure on the right is only beneficial if a user has a need to have an ability to look at multiple items on that tree from different parents at the same time. Example: ability to move Unit 1 into Building 2.  Why not use a different design pattern in this case?

Comment: The tree structure is beneficial in a large number of other cases, and it's actually the most common way to represent a multi-level hierarchy, such as the one we have here. The question "why not use a different solution" is a bit odd unless a concrete alternative is provided for the comparison.

Comment: I 100% agree that in very complex structures, navigation tree pattern is the most applicable. Given this example, however, I was curious if there are better (more simplified) options perhaps. A pattern similar to an off canvas nav (assuming the need to solve this for multi-device)